# HTML5: Non-replaced vs. replaced element?

Tags: html

I see [section 10.3 Non-replaced elements in the HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#non-replaced-elements). I was able to find the definition via Google, but where's the W3C HTML5 definition for non-replaced vs. replaced elements?

Answer (score 25):

From the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html):

> **Replaced Element**
>
> An element whose content is outside the scope of the CSS formatting model, such as an image, embedded document, or applet. For
>   example, the content of the HTML IMG element is often replaced by the
>   image that its "src" attribute designates. Replaced elements often
>   have intrinsic dimensions: an intrinsic width, an intrinsic height,
>   and an intrinsic ratio. For example, a bitmap image has an intrinsic
>   width and an intrinsic height specified in absolute units (from which
>   the intrinsic ratio can obviously be determined). On the other hand,
>   other documents may not have any intrinsic dimensions (for example, a
>   blank HTML document).
>
> User agents may consider a replaced element to not have any intrinsic dimensions if it is believed that those dimensions could
>   leak sensitive information to a third party. For example, if an HTML
>   document changed intrinsic size depending on the user's bank balance,
>   then the UA might want to act as if that resource had no intrinsic
>   dimensions.
>
> The content of replaced elements is not considered in the CSS rendering model.

Comment: Ah yes, that's much better than my answer was. Don't know why I couldn't find it.