# Margin top in inline element

Tags: html, css, inline, margin

My question is pretty simple:

Why is the margin top ignored for inline elements in firefox?

Does anyone know?

Comment: It's not just margin that doesn't work the same with inline elements as with blocks, padding is also treated differently. You can use inline-block instead to solve it.

Comment: Is inline-block cross browser?

Comment: It works in everything but older versions of IE. But inline might work in those browsers. Not sure.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is not Firefox-only, and defined in the [CSS 2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties):

> #### 8.3 Margin properties: 'margin-top', 'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', 'margin-left', and 'margin'
>
> Margin properties specify the width of the [margin area](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#box-margin-area) of a box. The 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. These properties apply to all elements, **but vertical margins will not have any effect on non-replaced inline elements.**

<sup>(Emphasis at the end is mine; `margin-top` is a vertical margin)</sup>

Comment: What are "non-replaced"?
Is there a good reason for this restriction?

Comment: @Tony Examples of replaced (inline) elements are textareas and images. Non-replaced inline elements are inline elements which are not a [replaced element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements).

Comment: The replaced elements link is invalid, here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012297/html5-non-replaced-vs-replaced-element

Answer (score -1):

inline elements can apply only margin letf and right but if you are using firefox it also appear margin bottom and top after inspect element but it doesn't apply realy