# How to get the rendered top margin of any element

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

I'm looking for a robust way of determining the top margin of any DOM node that is rendered in the browser. This should work in all browsers. How can I do this? (Sometimes an element may have a specified margin in a stylesheet, but it may not actually be rendered by the browser if, for example, it has `display:inline;` (see [Margin top in inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324527/margin-top-in-inline-element)). I'm looking for the actual rendered margin. Therefore, using `getComputedStyle()` won't work)

Comment: actual redenered margin, so if the element has display inline, did you want js to return margin 0 or the margin that is set on the element in the css? sorry I am just confused, need a little clarification

Comment: He wants it to return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so does the following approach work?

Check if element is display inline, if so the margin top is 0

if not then get top margin

Comment: @user730569 probably need some testing but in theory it should work

Comment: My only question is, are there any other styles you would need to check for?

Comment: @user730569 you will find out soon enough :)

Answer (score 0):

There MIGHT be a way to do this with JQuery. If it's not what you want, I think you got what I'm after, maybe it can help you find something.

```
function getRenderedTopMargin(id){
   var prevElementWidth;
   var elementOffset = $('#'+id).offset();
   var prevElementOffset = $('#'+id).prev().offset();
   if ($('#'+id).css("display") == 'inline' || $('#'+id).prev().css("display") == 'inline'){
       prevElementWidth = 0;
   }else{
       prevElementWidth = $('#'+id).prev().width();
   }
   return elementOffset.top - prevElementOffset.top - prevElementWidth;
}
```