# First-child not working on a tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The first-child pseudo-class selector doesn't seem to be having any effect. Here's the CSS, followed by HTML:

```
.social-block a:first-child {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 <div class="social-block">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="stylesheets/img/socialblock-facebook.png" alt="socialblock-facebook" width="300" height="125"></a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="stylesheets/img/socialblock-twitter.png" alt="socialblock-twitter" width="300" height="125"></a>
 </div>
```

Can't tell where I'm going wrong!

Comment: Many browsers don't support such selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top and bottom margins are not applied to inline elements. See similar question: [Margin top in inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324527/margin-top-in-inline-element).

To give `<a>` a bottom margin, you could try making it a block level element using `display: block`. However, that will push the second link onto the next line, so you may have to incorporate additional techniques (e.g. float) to make the two links appear side-by-side.

More on inline elements: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

By the way, the `:first-child` pseudo-class is not fully supported in IE 8.0 or earlier. See [CSS contents and browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly older versions of browsers do not support pseudo selectors.
Secondly
You are using margin-bottom on an **inline** Element. Margin-bottom is a property of block elements.

```
a:first-child{display:block;margin-bottom:12px;}
```

will work.