# Basic HTML/CSS - margin & display behaviour

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a basic question regarding HTML/CSS and the behaviour of margins from certain elements.
To make my point clear, I created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5VA5h/

You see, I applied some kind of "reset" and added some styles to all `h1`.
In the first example, the `margin` from `h1` is applied on the outside of the box, while in `#c`, where `h1` is set `display: inline;`, it is applied inside the box.

Why is this so?

Comment: Because inline and block-level elements are rendered differently in the browser.

Comment: you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324527/margin-top-in-inline-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, with the `<h1>` as a block element, the top [margin is collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) (emphasis mine):

> In CSS, the **adjoining** margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

...and later:

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> - both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting context
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them (Note that certain zero-height line boxes (see 9.4.2) are ignored for this purpose.)
> - both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
>   - **top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child**
>   - bottom margin of box and top margin of its next in-flow following sibling
>   - bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent if the parent has 'auto' computed height
>   - top and bottom margins of a box that does not establish a new block formatting context and that has zero computed 'min-height', zero or 'auto' computed 'height', and no in-flow children

The second example, with the `<h1>` as an inline element, the [vertical margins do not take effect](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties):

> The 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. These properties apply to all elements, but **vertical margins will not have any effect on non-replaced inline elements**.

Answer (score 0):

Margin-Top and Margin-Bottom is not used by elements with display:inline;
See: [Margin top in inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324527/margin-top-in-inline-element)

Comment: Where in your link does it ratify your statement that inline elements "aren't used"?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324527/margin-top-in-inline-element 

Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. These properties apply to all elements, but vertical margins will not have any effect on non-replaced inline elements.

Comment: ...which makes your statement "margin is not used by elements with `display: inline` glaringly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Top and Bottom margins in inline elements are not important. In inline elements, each element represents a word in a text.