# Html element alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I have created header in the top of page as give below. But why it keeps space from top page border even though I have kept margin 0?

[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/Uwucd/)

```
<body><div class="page-header header" style="color:fff; font-size: large; font-family: Arial;
">
            <h1 class="page-header-text">Review Networks</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: Having `<body>` is superfluous. It's already inside of a body element.

Comment: It's called margin-collapse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic HTML/CSS - margin & display behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358862/basic-html-css-margin-display-behaviour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the property `margin-top: 0;` to your `.page-header-text` selector.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwucd/4/) for a working code snippet of the vertical centering you want.

Comment: I want it to align in center vertically not the horizontal. This does not help

Comment: @Programming_crazy I will edit my answer once more, then. It's already center-aligned vertically.

Comment: @Programming_crazy I've added a JSFiddle which should give you the result you want.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I increase header height? without using pixel? I did `height:10%;` but did not help

Comment: @Programming_crazy `height:10%;` will specify a total element height of 10% of the parent element. What you can do is change `padding-top: 5px;` to `padding-top: 1%;` to achieve roughly the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Browsers add their own default styling, which was causing the margin issue with the h1. Setting margin: 0 auto; overrides that default styling. Auto tells the browser to split the remaining space between the left and the right of the element, thus centering it.

Comment: thanks but why text does not align in center? http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/Uwucd/1/

Comment: Programming_crazy, if you want the text to be centered, you just need to add 'auto' to the left and right margins. I updated my answer with this. Also be sure to include text-align: center;

Comment: @Hiran: I want it to align in center vertically not the horizontal. This does not hep

Comment: @HiramHibbard Could you add a little more description about why it works?

Comment: @Kevin sure. Updated my answer to give a few more details.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do that like this;

my first answer was : fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TPQnx/2/

As you don't want `position:absolute;`

**new** fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TPQnx/3/

Changes I've made:

added this to header class:

```
text-align:center;
```

and added;

```
h1 {
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay I've handled it. Editing the answer

Comment: thanks, but `height:10%;` why it does not increase header height? I dont want to use pixel for height

Comment: it's funny cause when I change the font-size to e.g 16px it changes the header height proportionally. I'm trying to solve it somehow