# css left and top margin on bootstrap labels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my blog main page http://lowcoupling.com/
it is a tumblr blog based on Twitter bootstrap. I am trying to have the badges in the footer representing the main topics more separated vertically in this way:

```
<span style="margin-left:2px; margin-top:5px;"> <a href="http://lowcoupling.com/tagged/UML/chrono"><span class="label label-default">UML</span> </a></span>
```

the problem is that the left margin works but the top margin doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to set `display:block;` and float them to left. it is better that you create a class like this:
HTML:

```
<span class="footer-link">
<a href="http://lowcoupling.com/tagged/UML/chrono">
<span class="label label-default">UML</span>
</a>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span.footer-link{
   display:block;
   float:left;
   margin:5px 0 0 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Solution for no space between label

```
<span class="label label-default">UML</span>&nbsp;
<span class="label label-default">CSS</span>&nbsp;
```

You can use space instead of `&nbsp;` but using `&nbsp;` is recommended
as it will not be trimmed.

### Solution for vertical margin

Use `line-height` as the span will be treated as text. When the text is wrapped, you cannot use margin which apply to block.

```
<span class="label label-default" style="line-height: 30px;">UML</span>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` on parent span and then give margin top or bottom.

```
<span style="margin-left:2px; margin-top:5px; display: inline-block"> <a href="http://lowcoupling.com/tagged/UML/chrono"><span class="label label-default">UML</span> </a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertical margins are ignored on inline elements.

See: [Margin top in inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324527/margin-top-in-inline-element)

Lookup the meaning of `inline` elements and `block` elements in HTML.
Furthermore I recommend that you simply have a look at the StackOverflow's implementation of your so-called 'badges'

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
<span style="margin-left:2px; margin-top:5px;">
<a href="http://lowcoupling.com/tagged/UML/chrono">
<span class="label label-default">UML</span> 
</a>
</span>
```

You should have:

```
<a href="http://lowcoupling.com/tagged/UML/chrono">
<span style="margin-left:2px; margin-top:5px;"></span>
</a>
```