# Break underline around lowercase letters (g q p j y) while preserving background image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

By using the `text-shadow` technique outlined on this question - [Disable underline for lowercase characters: g q p j y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866336/disable-underline-for-lowercase-characters-g-q-p-j-y) it's possible to break the underline around lowercase letters that extend past the 'bottom' of the text line, when the background is a solid color.

However, obviously it doesn't work if there's a background image. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Mwd.jpg) an example of the problem. Is there any way I can preserve the background image while leaving space around the 'p'? There's no way to apply a background image to `text-shadow` in CSS, and I can't think of any other techniques that would make this possible. I'm open to any solution including jQuery, not just pure CSS approaches.