# Text shadow with text decoration

Tags: css

I am looking for a way to use a text shadow on the h2 tag, and also have an underline on the words. The problem is, the text shadow is on the underline as well. How do I make it so that the underline doesnt have the text shadow?

*

```
css:
.pagetitle {
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: grey;
}
```

*

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to separate the underline from the text. To do so you can generate the underline with background with `linear-gradient` or a pseudo-element (`::before`).

```css
.pagetitle {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent calc(100% - 2px), grey calc(100% - 2px));
}
```

```html
<h2 class="pagetitle">I'm the Page Title</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use the border, resetting line-height to bring it closer to text.

```css
.pagetitle {
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
  text-decoration-color: grey;
  color:green;
 border-bottom:solid;
  line-height:0.9em;
  width:max-content;/* use display:table; if max-content is not supported */
}
h1 + h1 { margin:auto;}/*possibly*/
```

```html
<h1 class="pagetitle">My page title underlined</h1>
<h1 class="pagetitle">My page title underlined & centered</h1>
```

A pseudo could also be used.

If you also wanted the underline to be cut off when letters go through it, then , here is a probable duplicate : [Disable underline for lowercase characters: g q p j y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866336/disable-underline-for-lowercase-characters-g-q-p-j-y/22924670#22924670)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the underline shadow independently, but what you could do is use a `border-bottom` or one of the other tricks described in this article:

https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/