# Margin not getting applied

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this piece of code:

```
          <div 
               *ngIf="loginForm.get('username').errors.required"
               class="md-margin--s md-margin__horizontal--l">
            <i class="icon icon-clear_20 i-class-top"></i>
            <span class="md-margin__left--s">Please Enter Username</span>
          </div>
```

This is the result in the UI:

[image]

I am not able to place the text at the center vertically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Margin top in inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324527/margin-top-in-inline-element)

Answer (score 0):

you should add a class to  with below CSS:

```
.wrapper{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:flex-start;
}
```