# data-icon not working in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: html, css

Any idea why this is working in Safari, but not Firefox and Chrome?

HTML:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" id="search" name="search" id="s" data-icon="s">
```

CSS:

```
#search[data-icon]:before {
    font-family: 'Pictos Custom';
    content: attr(data-icon);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is no input type search replace it with text

Comment: Yes, there is: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.search.html

Comment: Did you try to use another font? Maybe that causes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind you can't use pseudo-elements on [replaced elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012297/html5-non-replaced-vs-replaced-element) which includes `<img>` `<select>` `<input>` `<object>` etc. basically elements that have no  [content](http://www.red-team-design.com/css-generated-content-replaced-elements)

Refer to the [Visual Formatting Model in the 2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#block-replaced-width) for more info

Comment: Thanks @TimMedora, I thought I'd have to use a workaround like that in the end.