# HTML & CSS - Why can't I get rid of the gap below this image?

Tags: html, css

I really am struggling here

I think I'm going mad. I've been trying to sort this problem out for hours, and I've stripped it down to the barebones!

There is a margin/gap/space below any image I put into this code

https://jsfiddle.net/k2gjjk8s/

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000">hi</div>
<img src="assets/images/banner-top-beneath.jpg" style="width:600px;height:300px;margin:0;padding:0;border:1px solid #000">
<div style="border:1px solid #000">hi</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #000">hi</div>
```

Please save my sanity, what have I missed here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `display:block` on the `<img>` tag to eliminate the gap.

By default, `<img>` is an inline element, more exactly a [replaced inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012297/html5-non-replaced-vs-replaced-element), so it behaves like one by default.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/k2gjjk8s/1/

Use `display:flex` or `inline` for your images.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/